# Converting a math problem to dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming

Currently I'm working on an optimization problem for a course I'm doing with a fellow student. It's basically described by three equations.

[image: equations]

Where n is an index taking values between 1 and 1180, **Pr** is a known vector (meaning all values of this vector are known and constant) and we have to find the vector **Ps** that results in the minimum value of **Ef[1180]**.

Logically, the answer would be to set all values of **Ps[n]** to infinity. However, there are a few constraints:

[image: Constraints]

Furthermore, the values of **Es** and **Ps** must always be a multiple of 1,000 to decrease the state space.

The above is what we figured out from the assignment description. However, we can't seem to figure out how to solve this as a dynamic programming problem. There are lots of examples around for going from a set of equations to a dynamic programming problem. However, those examples all have two or three inputs and use a 2- or 3-dimensional dictionary resp. to facilitate data reuse. We essentially have 1180 inputs. Creating an 1180-dimensional dictionary is not feasible

We tried constituting Bellman equations for this problem, but the professor told us this is wrong. Then we considered brute forcing the state space, but this is an insane job since there are 43^1180 possible combinations of input vectors **P_s**. Some of our fellow students advised us to checkout the checkerboard example on this wikipedia page:

[Wikipedia page on dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)

However, this example seems to traverse through the checkerboard only once. The usage of a cost function would always pick the highest possible value for **Ps[n]** to minimize **Ef[n]**. However, to do pick such a positive value we must have **Es[n] > 0** which can only happen when previous elements of **Ps[i]** for **i < n** take negative values. But the cost function will prevent **Ps** from having negative values. Since the cost function does not allow negative values and the **Es[n] >= 0** constraint does not allow negative values, this will result in a **Ps** containing only zeroes, which certainly does not result in the lowest value of **Ef[1180]**.

Any hints on how to continue would be nice. We have been staring at this problem for days now and we are completely lost at this point.

Comment: what is a_m, negative, positive?

Comment: Good question, it's positive: 2.42.

Comment: I got some help from a friend and I am working on a solution. I will post when I solve it. But feel free to comment if you have some tips!

Answer (score 1):

You want to minimize E[1180] idem maximize f defined below:

```
f(P) = \sigma_{i=1}^{1180} P_i
```

under constraint:

```
forall n <= 1180
  -6.5*10^5 <= \sum_{i=1}^n P_i <= 0
```

#### Recurrence formula be like

```
f(i, sumPs, v) {
  if i == 1180
    return { s: sumPs, solution: v }

  res = { s: -infinity, solution: [] }
  # Pr(i) > Ps(i)
  for psi in -21:min(Pr[i], 21)
    # Es(n-1) = - sumPs
    if psi <= -sumPs
      tmp = f(i+1, sumPs + psi, v+[psi])
      if tmp.s > res.s
        res.s = tmp.s
        res.v = tmp.v
  return res
}
f(0, 0, [])
```

#### Dynamic approach be similar:

Initialize the first layer: an associative array for `sumPs` as key and `{s:sum, v:facultative}` as value

We could actually just store nothing as value and use a set (stocking the sums), but it is convenient for debugging purpose

initialiaztion

```
for psi in -21:min(Pr[0], 0)
  layer[psi] = {s: psi, v:[psi]}
```

To build layer `i+1`, you only need layer `i`

```
for i = 2:1180
  nextLayer = []
  for psi in range(-21, min(Pr[i-1], 21))
    for candidate in layer:
      if psi <= -candidate.s
        maybe = candidate.s + psi
        if !nextLayer[maybe]
          nextLayer[maybe] = {s: maybe, v:v+[psi]}
  layer = nextLayer
```

NB: I have not handled the 1000 factor, but that should not be a problem

```js
const Pr = [-10,2,-2,4,-1]
function f(i, sumPs, v) {
  if (i == 5) {
    return { s: sumPs, v }
  }

  let res = { s: -1e12, v: [] }
  for (let psi = -21; psi<=Math.min(Pr[i], 21); ++psi) {
    if (psi <= -sumPs) {
      let tmp = f(i+1, sumPs + psi, v.concat(psi))
      if (tmp.s > res.s) {
        res.s = tmp.s
        res.v = tmp.v
      }
    }
  }
  return res
}

function dp(n, pr){
  let layer = new Map
  for (let psi = -21; psi <= Math.min(Pr[0], 0); ++psi) {
    layer.set(psi, {s: psi, v:[psi]})
  }
  for (let i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
    let nextLayer = new Map
    for (let psi = -21; psi <= Math.min(pr[i-1], 21); ++psi) {
      for (let [k, candidate] of layer) {
        if (psi <= -candidate.s) {
          const maybe = candidate.s + psi
          if (!nextLayer.has(maybe)) {
            nextLayer.set(maybe, { s: maybe, v: candidate.v.concat(psi) })
          }
        }
      }
    }
    layer = nextLayer
  }
  return [...layer.entries()].sort((a,b) => b[0] - a[0])[0][1]
}

console.log(f(0,0,[]))
console.log(dp(5,Pr))
```

Comment: I haven't checked your solution yet because I am still working on an implementation I am trying but I am already gonna give you an upvote for the effort. I will get back to you later.

Comment: as long as you have ideas it is always better to go your way. If you ever fallback on my way for "hints" I may have overlooked a few constraints but this should not change the spirit